# How can kext automatically load when booting Mac os?

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel-extension

My kext file should be loaded automatically at mac os boot time.

It currently appears in / Library / Extention, but it does not seem to be loaded automatically at boot time.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

For it to load automatically, it must either be an IOKit based kext, or another kext that gets loaded must depend on it.

If it's an IOKit kext, and there is no specific device which should trigger the loading of the kext, you can simply match the `IOResources` object. The [official documentation on device & driver matching](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Matching/Matching.html) talks about how to set up matching in general, and about matching IOResources specifically.